# How to save row in table with assigned primary key in MVC3 nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I hav a table with following fields

```
  public class ActivationCode
{
  public virtual int LoginAccountId { get; set; }
   public virtual string ActivatedCode { get; set; }
   public virtual DateTime ActivationDate { get; set; }
}
```

where LoginAccountid is my primary key and mapped as

```
 <id name="LoginAccountId">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

While saving i am assigning LoginAccountId as my users account id
bt while saving it is taking its own id and saving the data
i tried to save the data with both
Session.Save(); and Session.SaveorUpdate
bt in  Session.SaveorUpdate its giving me error as

```
    Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1.
```

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-assigned):

> 5.1.5.7. Assigned Identifiers
>
> If you want the application to assign identifiers (as opposed to
>   having NHibernate generate them), you may use the `assigned` generator.
>   This special generator will use the identifier value already assigned
>   to the object's identifier property. Be very careful when using this
>   feature to assign keys with business meaning (almost always a terrible
>   design decision).
>
> Due to its inherent nature, entities that use this generator cannot be
>   saved via the ISession's SaveOrUpdate() method. Instead you have to
>   explicitly specify to NHibernate if the object should be saved or
>   updated by calling either the `Save()` or `Update()` method of the
>   ISession.